# display letter to show statistical significance on ggplot bar graph

Tags: r, graph, anova, letter

I have a data frame, and the head looks like below, and there are more rows with different names and readings:

```
df <- data.frame ("name" = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
                  "reading" = c(3.6, 1.2, 3.1, 5.5, 6.1, 6.3, 9.3, 9.1, 8.9))
```

I use the following code to produce a bar graph:

```
ggplot(aes(x=name, y=reading))+geom_col()+stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", color="red")+stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", color="red")
```

I then performed ANOVA anlysis/TukeyHSD separately, but I could not add the letters to the graph showing if each two name-pairs are statistically different. 
May I ask if this be achieved by the ggplot queries without performing separate ANOVA/Tukey test?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `ggplot` is a graphing package---it's very good at graphing the data you give it. You may be able to hack together something so that your statistical test is done and results are computed all within ggplot, but it will probably be much easier if you perform a separate ANOVA with Tukey test and give ggplot the results.

Comment: You're welcome! All that to say---I think you'll get helpful answers if you include the code for your ANOVA/Tukey test and relax the *"be achieved by ggplot performing separate ANOVA/Tukey test"* constraint. If you don't do that, I doubt you'll have much success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
library(tidyverse)
stat_pvalue <- df %>% 
  rstatix::tukey_hsd(reading~name) %>% 
  rstatix::add_y_position(fun = "max")

ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=reading))+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="bar") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", color="red")+
  ggpubr::stat_pvalue_manual(stat_pvalue,  label = "p.adj.signif") +
  ggpubr::stat_compare_means(method = "anova")
```

[image]